# Pointwise convergence of $f(x)= \lbrace{ n^2x , 0\le x\le\frac{1}{n}; \quad 2n-n^2x,\frac{1}{n}< x\le\frac{2}{n};\quad 0, else }\rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis

Does
$$f(x)= \lbrace{ n^2x ,\quad  0\le x\le\frac{1}{n};  \quad 2n-n^2x,\quad\frac{1}{n}< x\le\frac{2}{n};\quad 0,\quad else }\rbrace$$
Pointwise convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f_n(x)= \lbrace{ n^2x ,\quad  0\le x\le\frac{1}{n};  \quad 2n-n^2x,\quad\frac{1}{n}\le x\le\frac{2}{n};\quad 0,\quad else }\rbrace$$
then for every $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $f_n(0)=0$ and for every $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ $f_n(\epsilon)=0\qquad \forall n>{2\over\epsilon}$. This exactly means pointwise convergence. This example has been mentioned in "Real Mathematical Analysis" by Charles Pugh

Comment: Can you please explain why $f=0$?
If we set $x=\frac{1}{n}$ then $f\_{n} (\frac{1}{n})=n$ which I'm sure not going to zero as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @Y.ofir In pointwise convergence you fix $x$ and let $n\to \infty.$ In your example, $x$ is not fixed.

Comment: I'm agree with "zhw". In pointwise convergence you need to fix n...

Comment: Well said. Thank you both

Comment: Don't mention it!